# How to get wall points without its openings in Revit api

Tags: revit-api

I was wondering if there a way to get the points of the wall without its openings like windows and doors.

When I get the faces, edge loops, edge and finally the line origin, they always retrieve the points of the wall after excluding the openings -I mean the corner points of the openings are returned also- which is not what I want, I want to get the original outline of the wall.

I tried to think of some equation to solve this but it will work for rectangular walls only with some tricks, but not for all cases.

So any ideas about that? 
Thanks in advance!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many possible approaches to solve this. Several were mentioned in the recent [Revit API discussion forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bd-p/160) thread on [getting face without inserts](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/get-face-without-inserts/m-p/7375289).